# Vectorization for Time Difference Loop in R

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I have a very large dataset (`df`) of events where each row corresponds to a measurement, time point (`df$TimeSec`), and event ID (`df$Source`).

The loop below creates a column, `df$TimeDiff`, which calculates the time difference between the current row time stamp and the next one. It also checks whether the `Source` has changed so the first row of a new event has a `TimeDiff` of `NA`.

I'm trying to shift my mindset from looping to taking advantage of R's vectorization and hope to increase speed of processing.

```r
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df$Source[i+1] == df$Source[i]){
    df$TimeDiff[i+1] <- df$TimeSec[i+1] - df$TimeSec[i]
  }else{
    df$TimeDiff[i+1] <- NA
  }
}
```

In summary the above loop does exactly what I want it to do, but I want to see if there's a better way that saves time of processing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found another solution using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Source) %>% 
  mutate(TimeDiff = TimeSec - lag(TimeSec))
```

Ran through the process in the blink of an eye.

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers for time series is using the `ts` library or similar. In base R we have the `diff` and `lag` function. Also the `ifelse` function simplifies vectorization of `if(){}else{}` sentences.

For your particular problem you could vectorize the if statement first:

```
cond <- diff(df$source) == 0 #if two sources are equal, their difference is 0
```

Next we can perform the entire calculation using a single `ifelse` call

```
df$TimeDiff <- 0 #initial column value
df$TimeDiff[-1] <- ifelse(cond, diff(df$TimeSec), NA)
```

This should be rather fast.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This definitely solves it, and after a bit more digging I found another solution which also solved the problem that I'll post.

Comment: Glad i could help :-)